# How to get HTML from AJAX Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using `XMLHttpRequest` to pull down the HTML from a specified URL, then stored it in `fshtml`. I then used:

```
function showInWindow(fshtml) {
    var newWindow = window.open();
    newWindow.document.write(fshtml);
}
```

To display all the HTML in a new window. But the HTML does not contain any of the code from the AJAX table in the middle of the page, which is what I want to access. Is there a way to use `XMLHttpRequest` to include the static version of the AJAX table HTML in `xhr.responseText`?

EDIT: This code pulls down html from the website:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://www.flashscore.com/basketball/", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        return showInWindow(xhr.responseText);
    }
}

xhr.send();
```

The new window had HTML for all the headers and tabs and such, but there didn't appear to be any table data. Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "AJAX table"?

Comment: the page has a table in the middle that loads values with AJAX. like there's tabs that can filter the data but it doesn't reload the page or change the url. i just want to access the HTML from the original table, but xhr.responsetext didn't pull it down

Comment: Maybe you should try xhr.responseText instead? Text register matters.

Comment: sorry, it's a typo. clearly i wouldn't have been able to pull any html at all if i had that bug in my actual code, but as i said, the html that did come down seemed to be everything but the table.

Comment: Well, html itself cannot be random text =). Can you show the fshtml file and maybe the controller or whatever you use for client-server?

Comment: edited original post to include more info. the website above is the one i want, with the big table in the middle

Comment: That will most likely not work – even if you get it to execute the AJAX code from the page you loaded into your popup window, it will run “under” your domain then – and therefor the Same Origin Policy will most likely block you from getting that data. Instead of “pseudo-scraping” this website, you should see if the offer an API to get the data you want, and if not, go _ask_ them if they are willing to provide that data to you in an easily accessible way – and ask if they even _permit_ you to use that data on your site first.

Comment: @CBroe it's a chrome extension, so i've circumvented the same origin policy by including the site under permissions in the manifest file, that's not the problem. could it be that HTML from an AJAX element cannot be retrieved in this way?